# How to disable plugin capability : "create new category"

Tags: plugins, functions, customization, user-roles, capabilities

I tested that a capability can be disabled for any user role, but I found nothing to block the capability of a plugin. Is this possible?

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can block the capability of a plugin by not using it :)

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I want to use plugin with limited capability

Comment: @RiddleMeThis thanks for comment

Comment: You would probably need to edit the plugin, creating your own version, then add/remove the capabilities.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I searched for adding/removing plugin capabilities documentation but found nothing

Comment: I don't think you can limit the capabilities of a plugin like your thinking, I'm suggesting you will have to edit the plugin directly.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis ok, thanks